# Not displaying the text by default for the first one in bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four divisions. I have used Bootstrap Accordion to display and hide the text.

By default, it should display the text when the user clicks on second one, the first one should get hidden and the second one should be displayed. And the four divisions should be in a single row instead of displaying one by one.

As of now, it is displaying in a single line but the problem is when the user clicks on second, third or fourth `div`, the remaining are moving down. The positions of the `div`s should not be changed, it should be the same, only the text related to that `div` should be changed.

By default, the first will be selected. The selected's color should be orange and for the rest of them the opacity should be light in color.

Here is the code for that and the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svsqhhe8/3/) link

**HTML**

```
<div class="servicesecommerce accordion itemsss-0 ">Ecommerce Development</div>
<div class=" servicesetext panel">
    <div class="services3">
        When it comes to E-Commerce websites you need a partner that is focused
        and experienced in providing companies the best in professional E-Commerce
        web design solutions. With a team of experts under one roof, Our goal is
        to provide you with all of the necessary design, development and marketing
        services you need to be successful online.
        We build E-Commerce Shopping Cart Applications, E-Commerce store front &
        custom e-commerce shopping cart development solutions.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="servicesecommerce accordion itemsss-1 ">Software Testing</div>
<div class=" servicesetext panel">
    <div class="services3">
        We provide a full suite of QA services in order to follow all of your
        changing QA requirements:
        > QA Process Evaluation
        > QA Requirements Analysis
        > QA Process Design
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS

```
.opacty {
    opacity: .3;
}
  div.panel {
padding: 0 18px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
div.panel, img.img-responsive.careerpage {
display: none;
}
.servicesecommerce.accordion.itemsss-1 {
    word-spacing: 9999999px;
    margin-left: 262px;
}
.servicesecommerce.accordion.itemsss-2 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left: 463px;
}
.servicesecommerce.accordion.opacty.itemsss-3 {
    margin-left: 663px;
}
.servicesecommerce.panel, .servicesoftwares.panel,
.servicesdigital.panel, .servicesmobile.panel {
    display: block !important;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #F4F4F4;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    text-align: justify;
}
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #ffffff !important; 
    border-color: #ffffff !important; 
}
.navbar {
    position: initial !important;
}
.servicesecommerce {
    background: #FF5E43;
    width: 189px;
    height: 66px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #FF5E43;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-left: 62px;
}
.servicesetext.panel.show {
    background: none;
    border: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
    height: 100%;
}
.col-md-9.servicessss {
    height: 100%;
}
.servicesecommerce.accordion.itemsss-1,
.servicesecommerce.accordion.itemsss-2,
.servicesecommerce.accordion.itemsss-3 {
    margin-top: -66px;
}
.panel {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.05) !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.05); 
}
div.panel.show {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
img.img-responsive.servicespageimage {
    display: block !important; 
}
```

**JS**

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}

$('.servicesecommerce').not('.servicesecommerce:first').addClass('opacty');
$('.servicesecommerce').click(function(e) {
    $('.servicesecommerce').not(this).addClass('opacty');
    $(this).removeClass('opacty'); 
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle is not working/empty css&js and your posted code is not bootstrap accordion. Are you trying to make an accordion?

Comment: @slashsharp https://jsfiddle.net/svsqhhe8/3/ this is the link

Comment: are you trying to make an accordion?

Comment: @slashsharp yes

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/0zmLxyc6/ when i click on ecommerce software testing is getting down it should not move down it should be in same line only the text should be changed and by default the ecommerce text should be displayed

Comment: Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/0zmLxyc6/

Comment: Can anyone help me these please

Comment: can anyone help me these thanks in advance

Comment: Please can anyone help me these

Comment: this is not bootstrap accordion

Comment: @slashsharp can you please the post the answer once which you have deleted

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bs-example">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please add a fiddle link so that i can check

Comment: Actually the data which i present it is dynamic data which we get from database and display in front end

Comment: It should not display one by one it should be in a single line

Comment: It is a dynamic data which i am fetching from database and displaying in front end

Comment: do you want to generate this accordion dynamically?

Comment: yes i am storing the data in database fetching and displaying in front end using accordion class

Comment: I have updated the fiddle link can you please check it

Comment: I think you are looking something for like this : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_pills_dynamic&stacked=h